# How to generate a totally positive matrix randomly using software like Maple?

Tags: linear-algebra, math-software

A matrix $A$ is [totally positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_positive_matrix) if all the minors of $A$ are positive. How to generate a totally positive matrix randomly using some software like Maple or any other CAS? Thank you very much.

Comment: to be clear, you don't want it in Maple, but any CAS would do, like Mathematica?

Comment: @SK19, thank you very much. I will edit the post.

Comment: symbolically or numerically?

Comment: @percusse, numerically. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We can first generate a random sequence L. Let $A$ be the Vandermonde matrix generated by sort(L). Then $A$ is totally positive. Then we compute the Gaussian LDU decomposition of $A$: $A = utv$. The matrices $u, t, v$ are all totally positive. Let $B=vtu$. Then $B$ is totally positive. The matrix $B$ is a random totally positive matrix.